# Story about a military agent sent in to kill or retrieve a female spy from behind enemy lines

Tags: identification-request

The story is about a military agent with an incident in his military record (Something about a hostage situation if I remember correctly) that indicates he's soft and is not fine with mindlessly spending other lives in the name of collateral damage.

This soldier is sent behind enemy lines to retrieve or kill a captured female spy. The soldier is told that this spy has documents of crucial plans regarding a planned invasion (at arbitrary city "A") by the spy's and the soldier's country.

I don't remember the country but the story had ample mentions of the tommy gun.

The soldier goes with a squad and after a time see a column of smoke from a cave where the spy was burning the important documents she had. The spy gets captured, and though the soldier has a chance to kill the spy using sniper from a hill, he doesn't.

Later he goes to enemy barracks to rescue the spy, and he and his squad gets captured. His squad mates are made to walk on minefield as means of execution. Somehow he survives and rescues the agent.

**The spy then tells him that the invasion plan documents for city A which the spy has are fake, and are a distraction for the real invasion which is supposed to happen in city B (another arbitrary city)**

The enemy tortures the soldier in front of the spy. The spy then pretends to break down and tells the enemy that their country is planning a invasion of city A. Later somehow the soldier (squad mates are dead) and the spy escape.

The enemy believes the rumours and fortifies city A, and city B is attacked. In the end, back in his country, the soldier goes to a restaurant in an oversized uniform to meet the spy.